# C# - Passar apenas numeros em um campo formatado para moeda

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Eu tenho uma aplicação que me apresenta em um textbox o valor de uma matricula de um curso:

```
string mensalidade = string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDouble(leitura["Mensalidade"]));
cursoSelecionado.Mensalidade = mensalidade;
tb_Mensalidade.Text = Convert.ToString(cursoSelecionado.Mensalidade);
```

Como podemos ver, o campo apresenta o valor desse curso formatado para o estilo moeda. 
Porém, eu preciso passar apenas o valor desse curso, como decimal, para o meu banco de dados (SQL Server).

```
inserirMatricula.Parameters.Add("@Mensalidade", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = ???;
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: como está o valor em `leitura["Mensalidade"]` ?

Comment: De um curso, como exemplo, está 1158.47. É o valor retornado na tabela do SQL.

Comment: Você não poderia passar essa variável para o seu banco de dados? esta formatação que você apresentou 1158.47, o sql server vai aceitar perfeitamente.

Comment: Sem problema algum. O problema é que o campo está formatado como moeda para uma melhor visualização do usuário(indicando um campo monetário). Além disso, quando o valor do curso é um inteiro, por exemplo, "875,00", o SQL me devolve sem as casas decimais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu uso este código. Assumo que o valor de leitura["Mensalidade"] seja como apresentado abaixo.

```
    private void Parse()
    {
        decimal x = 0;
        string mensalidade = string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDouble("23,3"));

        x = decimal.Parse(mensalidade, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.Number);

    }
```

Comment: E no caso, eu passo "mensalidade.Parse" nos parametros do Sqlcommand?

Comment: sim, Ajusta o metodo "Parse()" e podes fazer algo como inserirMatricula.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mensalidade", Parse(tb_Mensalidade.Text));